# Facebook - Photo posted with App is not publicly accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making Rails app that needs to view and post photo **to a specific Album of a Page**.

So User can view and Admin can upload.

I finished the uploading part but got a problem. The problem is: All photos that are uploaded by the App doesn't show up with the Graph API (`/<album_id>/photos`) even though it says **Public** when I view it in facebook.com.

[image]

I tried uploading the photo manually to the album and it shows up in my App just fine.

Is this intended behavior or there's a parameter that I need to pass?

**[EDIT]**

I just tested with Graph API Explorer. If I'm logged in with the Page's admin account, I can view all. If other account, can only view the photos that are uploaded via facebook.com.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got this figured out. My app is still on development mode. Activate it and all the photo will appear in the API call.

Answer (score 1):

While posting photo data to graph API, you need to set privacy of the photo.

[image: Photo Privacy Setting]

You need to pass `{'value': 'EVERYONE'}` as the value for `privacy` in your API call.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I just tried the `privacy` params and still got the same problem on my app. I want to try in API Explorer but got `OAuth Exception` since it's a Page's album. Any way to get Page's token in API Explorer?

Comment: Wait, the `OAuth Exception` is because I didn't set the `publish_action` permission. But after I set it, the photo is uploaded to my Personal wall even though I put in the Page's Album ID. I guess we need to get **Page's Access token**?

Comment: no you can work with `user's access token`. Because you are trying to upload photo in user's album